# If $A$ is positive definite, and $B$ is symmetric, when does $ABA$ have (strictly) positive diagonal elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I know that if $B$ is positive definite, then $ABA$ is also positive definite, and so this works. But I am looking for weaker conditions that can ensure a (weaker) result of positive diagonal elements, and I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: A simple notice: taking $A$ to be the identity matrix shows that any weaker condition has to use $A$ somehow.

Comment: ah yes, good point! although in that case, $B$ having positive diagonals would suffice, no?

Comment: $$
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \cr -1 & 2}
\pmatrix{1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1}
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \cr -1 & 2}
=\pmatrix{0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1}
$$

Comment: Any set of conditions about a self-adjoint matrix implying that its diagonal entries are positive, and which are stated w/out reference to a basis, is likely to also imply that the matrix itself is positive.  This is because you may always view things from the point of view of a basis of eigenvectors. In other words, proving  that the diagonal entries are positive is not really weaker than proving positivity.

Comment: But, don't you think by imposing conditions on both $A$ and $B$, we can achieve a weaker set of conditions on $B$?

Comment: The point of my last comment is that I think we can't.

Comment: I see. Do you think we would be able to show that if $ABA$ has a positive diagonal, then $B$ is positive definite? (under the current assumptions on $A$ and $B$ ofc)

Comment: Nope.  Try $A=\pmatrix{2&1\cr1&1}$ and  $B=\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1}$.

Comment: What if we can enforce that $B$ has positive diagonal?